# How to use DotNetBrowser on winforms ? getting some error

Tags: c#, winforms

a link to the example i'm trying to make using the DotNetBrowser:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/embed-google-maps-in-net-desktop-application/

I used the nuget packager manager browsed for DotNetBrowser.WinForms and installed the version 2.21.0

then created a new form and added this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DotNetBrowser.Browser;
using DotNetBrowser.Engine;
using DotNetBrowser.WinForms;
using DotNetBrowser;

namespace Weather
{
    public partial class DotNetBrowserTest : Form
    {
        private BrowserView browserView;

        public GoogleMapWinform()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            browserView = new BrowserView();
            this.Controls.Add((Control)browserView);
            browserView.Browser.LoadURL("http://microsoft.com");
        }

        private void GoogleMapWinform_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting error on this line that Browser is not exist:

```
browserView.Browser.LoadURL("http://microsoft.com");
```

The error:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'BrowserView' does not contain a definition for 'Browser' and no accessible extension method 'Browser' accepting a first argument of type 'BrowserView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Also consider adding link to the library/class documentation you are using.

Answer (score 3):

[The example you provided](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/embed-google-maps-in-net-desktop-application/) uses `WinFormsBrowserView` which only existed in earlier versions (1.x) of DotNetBrowser.

For current versions use the example provided in their documentation. You need to create an IEngine instance, use that to create an IBrowser instance, and pass the IBrowser to the BrowserView by `browserView.InitializeFrom(browser);`.

Example taken from [documentation for DotNetBrowser](https://dotnetbrowser-support.teamdev.com/docs/guides/gs/browser-view.html):

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DotNetBrowser.Browser;
using DotNetBrowser.Engine;
using DotNetBrowser.WinForms;

namespace Embedding.WinForms
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     This example demonstrates how to embed DotNetBrowser
    ///     into a Windows Forms application.
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private const string Url = "https://html5test.com/";
        private readonly IBrowser browser;
        private readonly IEngine engine;

        public Form1()
        {
            // Create the Windows Forms BrowserView control.
            BrowserView browserView = new BrowserView
            {
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            };

            // Create and initialize the IEngine instance.
            EngineOptions engineOptions = new EngineOptions.Builder
            {
                RenderingMode = RenderingMode.HardwareAccelerated
            }.Build();
            engine = EngineFactory.Create(engineOptions);

            // Create the IBrowser instance.
            browser = engine.CreateBrowser();

            InitializeComponent();

            // Add the BrowserView control to the Form.
            Controls.Add(browserView);
            FormClosed += Form1_FormClosed;

            // Initialize the Windows Forms BrowserView control.
            browserView.InitializeFrom(browser);
            browser.Navigation.LoadUrl(Url);
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            browser?.Dispose();
            engine?.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```